# Form handling in Pyramid

Tags: python, forms, pyramid, wtforms

Since Pyramid does not have any form dependencies, I need recommendations for form handling.
This covers form generation, validation, etc.
I only know wtforms, but I dont mind to use some other thing more advanced.

Comment: What's not *advanced* in WTForms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend deform.  Beyond supporting form generation and validation it has great documentation, a running demo app and it supports localization and ajax.  I don't believe formalchemy directly support ajax.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using FormAlchemy http://docs.formalchemy.org/pyramid_formalchemy/

Pyramid's author wrote Deform https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/dev/

Comment: lack of Python 3 support has kept me away from this one

Answer (score 3):

Go to the pseudo-standard form validator for pyramid:

[Simple Form validator and rendering library](http://packages.python.org/pyramid_simpleform/)